# Downloading file - prevent second download till first is done

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have download code functionality in my ASP.NET project and the download code look like below.

```
public class Download : IHttpHandler
{    
    private void DownloadPsListingProduct(Guid which)
    {
        string path = GetFilePathFromGuid(which);

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;        
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();

        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";        
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                           "attachment;filename=\"" + file.Name.NeutralizationCrlfSequences() + "\";");

        response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This code work like a charm when I download single file at a time.
But when one file is under process of downloading and I request to download other file then it first wait to completion of first file downloading and then second file download start.

Note: I am sending new request to download each file.

I want to avoid this single file download behavior and user should able to download files without waiting previous one to complete.

Comment: Do you *want* the single-file-at-a-time behavior, or are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: @TomasLycken I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: I'd somewhat expect this behaviour if your handler was marked as requiring session state but that doesn't appear to be the case here. Is this the genuine code?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this code was from the begin and on stackoverflow we can find this code. But I want some better approach to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you constricted to using `IHttpHandler`s, or could you e.g. implement it with a WebAPI controller instead?

Comment: @TomasLycken I can implement it with anything. Any new idea which can resolve this issue. You can advice me other way as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web API 2 should be able to handle this with very little ceremony. There's an example [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/ActionResults/ReadMe.txt), but I'll re-iterate the important parts:

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult(Guid fileId)
    {
        var filePath = GetFilePathFromGuid(fileId);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMappting(fileName);
        return OkFileDownloadResult(filePath, mimeType, fileName, this);
    }
}
```

Of course, hooking up routing etc in ASP.NET Web API 2 is quite different from hooking up an `IHttpHandler`, but there's also a plethora of examples on the internet (including here on SO) on how to get started with that.

Comment: I have ASP.NET project. Do I have to create separate Web API project? Or I can do in same ASP.NET Website with urlrewrite?

Comment: @imlim You should be able to add a Web API controller to your website project without problems. Do take a look at the documentation - there's lots of guides there: https://www.asp.net/mvc